# My internet access doesn't work after rebooting

Tags: networking, internet, 19.10

**When I turn my computer on normally**, I see these:

[image]

in my upper-right corner of the screen.

**If I *reboot* my system**, it becomes like this:

[image]

(the internet access symbol stops working).

Also, if I go to my internet settings in the *settings*, I normally see this:

[image]

(sorry for my system being in Portuguese). In this last image linked there appears a cabled network and some proxy and VPN settings. When I'm **in the after rebooting**, I don't see the first part (cabled network), I only see the proxy and VPN settings.

## Useful information:

- *Ubuntu version:* 19.10

### Asked information:

- Running the command `lspci | grep -i eth`:

  - Before rebooting: `02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)`
  - After rebooting, **nothing** is shown in the output

If necessary, I'll put more useful information here .

Comment: Please turn on your computer normally then run this in the terminal `lspci | grep -i eth` and [edit] your question an add the output then reboot and run the command again also adding the second output to your question.

Comment: @Raffa I added what you asked for.

Comment: Please go to your BIOS setup and disable ( quick boot or fast boot and quiet boot } options. Then try.again and see if the issue is solved

Comment: @Raffa Fast boot is already off. I didn't find any of the other options.

Comment: As it appears, after reboot the Ethernet card itself is not detected/not turned on. Find the option in the BIOS that causes this and change it or if you have a key or key combination to activate/deactivate the Ethernet cad, try using it .... sometimes this key is a dedicated key specific to your machine module and sometimes it is just a function key like `F1,F2,F3....etc.` or a combination of like `fn + F1, F2, F3 ....etc.`